# DevTools time steps

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

How can I enable this feature in Google Chrome? It works in another browser (Yandex) but not in Google Chrome. Here's a link to an image that describes the issue:
[image]

I tried using ChatGPT to solve this problem, but it couldn't help me.